# How to maintain full screen when changing scenes javafx

Tags: java

I have seen a similar question being asked, however my problem is that I want the stage to maintain full screen mode during the entirety of the scene change ie not simply adding `stage.setFullScreen(true)` at the end of it, which causes a momentary but very noticeable exit from full screen. Hiding the stage before changing scenes doesn't really help either, as there is a noticeable disappearance . Here's my code:

Main:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane pane;

    @FXML
    void doSomething(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Stage stage = (Stage) pane.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-
Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
      <Button layoutX="180.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
onAction="#doSomething" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="241.0" text="Do Something" 
/>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Sample2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-
Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"  style="-fx-background-color: blue;" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
      <Button layoutX="180.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
onAction="#doSomething" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="241.0" text="Do Something" 
/>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

As you can see, if you run the code and press the button, there is a momentary exit from full screen. Is there any way to fix this, other than using the same fxml file?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: so when you load the second screen and if you press escape you don't want to close the full screen?

Comment: No...I simply want a smooth transition from the first to the second. Right now the stage exits fullscreen then enters again. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: But on a completely different note, if you know how to make full screen not close when escape is pressed that would be extremely helpful too :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clearly understood what you are saying. I think you need a stage of size equals to Computer screen resolution and switch between the two screens. If yes then the following files will help you do so. If you want to come back to first scene from second scene then keep another button to load the first scene or keep a static variable and switch between the scenes by incrementing the variable and show the scene based on odd or even. Like for odd value of the variable show first scene and for even values show second scene.

Other process is getting the children of the stage. This gives you a ObservableList. Now clear the list and then add the respective scene to the list and show the stage.

**Main class:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        //set Stage boundaries to visible bounds of the main screen
        primaryStage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
        primaryStage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
        primaryStage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller Class:**

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane pane;

    @FXML
    void doSomething(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Stage stage = (Stage) pane.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 500, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        //set Stage boundaries to visible bounds of the main screen
        stage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
        stage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
        stage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
        stage.show();

    }
}
```